# Android Studio cannot build correctly with Expo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, react-native, expo

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles y estoy queriendo hacer una aplicación con módulos nativos en expo, y vi que para codificar mejor usaron Android Studio para Kotlin.

Me gustaría poder utilizar Android Studio para tener autocompletado y el resto de características que me hagan más cómodo trabajar.

**PROBLEMA:** Mi problema son dos cosas:

1 – No sé cuál de las dos carpetas de android debo abrir con Android Studio XD

2 - En caso de que sea el que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta de ejemplos, android me tira el error.

[image: Imagen con error]

En caso de que esa no sea la carpeta de Android para abrir, cuando abro la otra aparece un error con expo-modules-core.

¿Qué debo hacer para solucionarlo? Estuve buscando mucho en internet y no encontré mucho, tal vez no pude entender bien las soluciones que vi. Disculpe las molestias y ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: No sé que es Expo, pero si no es un proyecto nativo de Android seguramente tendrás que instalar algún plugin como este https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21395-expo

Comment: Estoy usando Expo para crear aplicaciones nativas con React Native. Y estoy utilizando el IDE de Android Studio, ese plugin no me sirve ya que no está para Android Studio. Busqué algo similar y no encontré. Quisiera utilizar este IDE, pero si no me queda otra, voy por IntelliJ